# Font awesome specific icon not loading

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

I download from here https://fontawesome.com/download version 6.2.1 and included all.css.
Many icons work. But I needed this icon: https://fontawesome.com/icons/magnifying-glass-dollar?s=regular&f=classic
solid version is displayed, but the regular version is not
What to do help

I connected different cdn and nothing works and it doesn't work in any browser and I don't want to connect js

Comment: According to you link this icon is a "pro" icon and not available in the free fontAwesome icon set

Comment: herrstrietzel, and where is it written? there is nothing about the fact that this badge is pro

Comment: There's a yellow button "Start Using This Pro Icon" and a notice if you try to download the icon.